# How to get the instance of current plugin object in class-based view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I am developing a plugin for django-cms.

Right now, I have a class `BaseMyPlugin` extending `CMSPlugin` class and I need to get an attribute `base_attr` from that class in class-based detail view (`MyDetailView`) context. What should I import (for modules) or override (for functions) for my view?

The attribute I want to get is set in runtime so I have to get the instance. It is reachable in the `template` context because there is an global instance of `plugin`. But in the view context, I can not get such an instance.

I have tried the following:

1. Import `BaseMyPlugin` class in the view context. Failed because it was not the instance.
2. Override `render_to_response`/`get_context_data`/`get_object` methods in `MyDetailView` class. Failed because the parameters of these methods didn't contain the `base_attr` attribute.

---

Code for my view:

````py
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    ```
    I want to get the BaseMyPlugin.base_attr in this view
    ```
    view_attr='to be set accouding to BaseMyPlugin.base_attr'
````

---

Code for my `CMSPlugin` class:

```py
class BaseMyPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    # target attribute
    base_attr='some value set in runtime'
```

---

I need to get the `base_attr` anyway to set `view_attr` in view in runtime. Could you help me plz?

Comment: How does your view come into play in your plugin? Usually a plugin doesn't have a view.

Comment: @markwalker_ Indeed, in the view context I can not find any plugin instance. So My workaround is put the value of plugin attribute into view request parameters. Then I can get the value from parameter in view context.

Comment: Hold up, a plugin doesn't have a view, so I don't think you can actually do what you want. If you need to integrate views with CMS, you need an apphook & full application with URLs.